# AbstractSoapInterceptor is not working with cxf:cxfEndpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, jax-ws, jbossfuse

I have tried to log a message from a cxf interceptor which extends AbstractSoapInterceptor and added that interceptor to  chain

**Blueprint.xml**

```
`<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="reportEndpoint" address="/report/"
        serviceClass="com.shajeer.integration.helloworld.incident.IncidentService">
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <bean id="inInterceptor"
            class="com.shajeer.integration.helloworld.logging.LoggingInSetupInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>`
```

**interceptor**

```
 `import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
    import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
    import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
    import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    public class LoggingInSetupInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingInSetupInterceptor.class);
        public LoggingInSetupInterceptor() {
            super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(SoapMessage soapMessage) throws Fault {
            System.out.println("In LoggingInSetupInterceptor :: LoggingInSetupInterceptor");
            LOGGER.info("In LoggingInSetupInterceptor :: LoggingInSetupInterceptor");       
        }
    }`
```

But the control flow is not even reaching the interceptor and directly going into the camel context. what can be the reason?

**cxf namespace declaration**

```
`xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check what is the message version wheteher it is **Soap11** or **Soap12** Add the below snippet and debug

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
      if (message.getVersion() instanceof Soap11) {
            Map<String, List<String>> headers = CastUtils.cast((Map)message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS));
            if (headers != null) {
                List<String> sa = headers.get("SOAPAction");
                if (sa != null && sa.size() > 0) {
                    String action = sa.get(0);
                    if (action.startsWith("\"")) {
                        action = action.substring(1, action.length() - 1);
                    }
                    getAndSetOperation(message, action);
                }
            }
        } else if (message.getVersion() instanceof Soap12) {

        }
```